# Adding Randomisation to GOL?

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

Here is my code for Game Of Life. Currently the game is being played from a seed file, however i wish to add randomisation which i'm struggling to do. Can somebody provide some input?

```
class LifeGrid
    {
            public int[][] CG; //New 2d Array called Current Generation
            public int[][] NG; //New 2d Array called NextGeneration
            public int x, y, Rows, Columns;

        public LifeGrid(int x, int y, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
        {   

            File file = new File(filename); //New File that directs to Seed
            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(file); //Scans the seed file

            CG = new int[x][y]; //Initialize CurrentGeneration with variables x and y referring to grid size
            NG = new int[x][y]; //Initialize NextGeneration with variables x and y
            this.x = x; //Makes x equal to x in constructor 
            this.y = y; //Makes y equal to y in constructor



            System.out.println("Original Seed File: "); //Prints the title for Seed File
            while(Scan.hasNextLine()) //Checks if there is another line after current line
            {
                System.out.println(Scan.nextLine()); //Scans each next line and prints it to screen
            }

            Scan.close(); //Closes the scanner
            Scan = new Scanner(file); //Reopens the scanner 

            while(Scan.hasNextLine()) //Checks if there is another line after current line
            {
                Rows++; //increments Rows variable by 1 until there is no line to scan 
                Scan.nextLine(); //Scans each next line 
            }

            Scan.close();
            Scan = new Scanner(file); 

            String c = Scan.next(); //Initializing a new String variable c that stores each character
            Columns = c.length(); //Variable column (defined on top) equals the length of C that contains characters

            System.out.println("Columns in Seed = " + Columns + "\nRows in Seed = " + Rows); //Rows,Columns     
            //^ Prints to screen Number of columns and rows in the seed file

            int xOffset = (((x-1)/2) - (Rows/2)); int yOffset = (((y-1)/2) - (Columns/2));
            //^ Places the seed into the middle of the grid

            Scan.close(); 
            Scan = new Scanner(file); 

            String ReadLine = Scan.nextLine(); //Initializing a string called ReadLine that stores each line in text file
            for(int i=xOffset; i<x; i++) //for loop that starts at the offset
            {
                for(int j=yOffset, k=0;k<ReadLine.length(); j++, k++)
                {   
                    if(ReadLine.charAt(k)=='*') //Checks if current line contains the character '*'
                    {
                        CG[i][j] = 1; //For all characters equal to '*', cell at i,j, equals 1
                    }
                }

                if(Scan.hasNextLine() == false) //If there are no more lines left to scan
                    break; // then stop
                else //Otherwise
                    ReadLine = Scan.nextLine(); //Continue reading the next line
            }   
        }
```

Game of life checking neighbours

```
            public int Neighbours(int xInput, int yInput) //Creates a new method called Neighbours that uses x and y inputs from 'LifeMain'
            {
                xInput -= 1; yInput -= 1; // x and y inputs equals x and y inputs minus 1
                int neighbour = 0; int incrementer = 0; //Creates new variables neighbour and incrementer
                int iMinus = -1, kMinus = -1, iPositive= 1, kPositive = 1; 

                if(yInput == 0) //if the y input (from grid) is zero
                    kMinus = 1; //Then make the K value equal to 1
                if(xInput == 0) //if the xInput is equal to zero
                    iMinus = 1; //set iMinus to 1
                if(yInput + 1 == x) //If the yInput + 1 is equal to the x value
                    kPositive = 0; //set kPositive equal to zero
                if(xInput + 1 == y) //If the xInput + 1 is equal to the y value
                    iPositive = 0; //set iPositive equal to zero
                for(int c = kMinus; c <= kPositive; c++) //for loop to start at -1 and increment but to remain less than or equal to 1
                {
                    if(c == 0) 
                        incrementer = 2; 
                    else
                        incrementer = 1;
                    for(int row = iMinus; row <= iPositive; row+=incrementer)
                    {
                        if(CG[yInput + c][xInput + row] == 1)
                            neighbour++; //Increment neighbour when the cell in Current Gen equals 1
                    }
                }
                    return neighbour;
            }

            public void show() //Method to Show Details
            {
                for(int i=0; i<y; i++) //Scans rows 
                {
                    for(int k=0; k<x; k++) //Scans columns 
                    {
                        if(CG[i][k] == 1) //Checks which cells are equal to 1
                        {
                            System.out.print("[*]"); //Replaces all cells containing 1 to [*]
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.print("[ ]"); //Cells with zero are replaced with empty grid 
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

Game of life rules

```
            public void Run() //Life Rules
            {
                for(int Row=1; Row<CG.length+1; Row++)
                {
                    for(int Column=1; Column<CG[0].length+1; Column++)
                    {
                        if(CG[Row-1][Column-1] == 1 && Neighbours(Column,Row) < 2)
                        {
                            NG[Row-1][Column-1] = 0;
                        }
                        else if(CG[Row-1][Column-1] == 1 && Neighbours(Column,Row) >3)
                        {
                            NG[Row-1][Column-1]=0;
                        }
                        else if(CG[Row-1][Column-1] == 1 && (Neighbours(Column,Row) == 2 || Neighbours(Column,Row) == 3))
                        {
                            NG[Row-1][Column-1]=1;
                        }
                        else if(CG[Row-1][Column-1] == 0 && Neighbours(Column,Row) == 3)
                        {
                            NG[Row-1][Column-1] =1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                show();

                for(int i=0; i<y; i++) //r = row. This scans the rows 
                {
                    for(int k=0; k<x; k++) //c = column. This scans the columns
                    {
                        CG[i][k] = NG[i][k]; //Makes the current generation equal to the next generation to print 
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up `java.util.Random`. You probably want to test `nextDouble()` against a population density.

It's normal to define 'random' spaces by a density (0.0 for empty to 1.0 for solid) of live cells.

Write a constructor:

```
#import java.util.Random;

//...

public LifeGrid(int x, int y, double density, Random rand){

    //Initialise - same a file reading constructor

    //Fill - 2 nested loops calling rand.

}
```